# Multiple joins to single table in SQL Server query throwing off counts

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, join, left-join, outer-join

I am writing a stored procedure in SQL Server Management Studio 2005 to return a list of states and policy counts for two different time periods, month to date and year to date. I have created a couple of views to gather the required data and a stored procedure for use in a Reporting Services report.

Below is my stored procedure:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    S.[State],
    COUNT(HP_MTD.PolicyID) AS PolicyCount_MTD,
    COUNT(HP_YTD.PolicyID) AS PolicyCount_YTD
FROM tblStates S
    LEFT OUTER JOIN vwHospitalPolicies HP_MTD ON S.[State] = HP.[State]
        AND HP.CreatedDate BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
    LEFT OUTER JOIN vwHospitalPolicies HP_YTD ON S.[State] = HP.[State]
        AND HP.CreatedDate BETWEEN DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
GROUP BY S.[State]
ORDER BY S.[State] ASC
```

The problem I am running into is my counts are bloating when a second LEFT OUTER JOIN is added, even the COUNT() that isn't referencing the second join. I need a left join since not all states will have policies for the given period, but they should still appear on the report.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried just a left join? without the outer

Comment: Yes, without a difference in the results.

Comment: @Taeeril - To my knowledge, most RDBMSs consider a `LEFT JOIN` to have an implicit `OUTER`; removing it will have no effect.

Comment: Most, but I have seen SQL treat it different on rare occasions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT HP_MTD.PolicyID) AS PolicyCount_MTD,
COUNT(DISTINCT HP_YTD.PolicyID) AS PolicyCount_YTD
```

instead of:

```
COUNT(HP_MTD.PolicyID) AS PolicyCount_MTD,
COUNT(HP_YTD.PolicyID) AS PolicyCount_YTD
```

Your original query is including the number of matching rows in the second join. Adding a `DISTINCT` clause inside the `COUNT` limits it to unique occurrences of the PolicyID.

Comment: Yes, this should likely solve the OP's problem, but could you maybe explain why?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer CTEs for this sort of work - they're basically a sort of inline view.

Your actual problem is that some policies are being counted twice - once for the month-to-date, and once for the year-to-date - in *both* count columns.  So, if you have source tables like this:

```
year-to-date
state   policy
==================
1       1
1       2
1       3
2       4

month-to-date
state   policy
==================
1       1
1       2
```

The result table for the `JOIN`s (before `COUNT` is assesed) looks like this:

```
temp
state  monthPolicy  yearPolicy
================================
1      1            1
1      1            2
1      1            3
1      2            1
1      2            2
1      2            3
2      -            4
```

Clearly not what you want.  Often, the solution is to use a CTE or other table reference to present summed-up records for the final join.  Something like this:

```
WITH PoliciesMonthToDate (state, count) as (
                          SELECT state, COUNT(*)
                          FROM vwHospitalPolicies
                          WHERE createdDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())
                          AND createdDate < DATEADD(DAY, 1, GETDATE())
                          GROUP BY state),
     PoliciesYearToDate (state, count) as (
                         SELECT state, COUNT(*)
                         FROM vwHospitalPolicies
                         WHERE createdDate >= DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE())
                         AND createdDate < DATEADD(DAY, 1, GETDATE())
                         GROUP BY state)
SELECT a.state, COALESCE(b.count, 0) as policy_count_mtd, 
                COALESCE(c.count, 0) as policy_count_ytd
FROM tblStates a
LEFT JOIN PoliciesMonthToDate b
ON b.state = a.state
LEFT JOIN PoliciesYearToDate c
ON c.state = a.state
ORDER BY a.state
```

(minor nitpick - don't use prefixes for tables and views.  It's noise, and if for some reason you switch between them, it would require a code change.  That, or the name would then be misleading)

Comment: Unfortunately I am working in a database where all the objects are prefixed. Also, I want policies picked up the MTD count to show up in the YTD count.

Comment: (oops, corrected date-range typo)  Just something to keep in mind, I know you may not be able to modify your current schema.  Also, the two counts are independent, logically - you don't ask SQL to 'count everything in the last year, and if it happens to be in the last month, add it to this other count', you ask it to 'count everything in the last year' and 'count everything in the last month'.  If a policy was created in the last month, it will be counted once for each count.